# Pagination on php foreach loop by this image editor

Tags: php, foreach, pagination

help by foreach pagination php
i have this code:

```
/*loop trough folders and show images from each folder*/
foreach ($folders as $folderNames2) {

?>
<div class="sEditorEffectsSampleImages" id="<?php echo $folderNames2; ?>List">
    <?php

    //list images from each folder
    /*search .png files in each folder andd create effect list form png names*/
    $files = glob($settingsValue['effectsFolder'] . '/' . $folderNames2 . '/*.png');
    /*if there is images in folder list them*/
    if (count($files > 0)){
    ?>

    <?php
    /*loop trough each folder and outpu image names*/

    foreach ($files as $name) {
        $path = explode('/', $name);
        $name = explode('.', $path[2]);
        //echo '<li id="'.$name[0].'" idf="'.$folderNames.'"><a href="#">'.$name[0].'</a></li>';
        //echo $name[0]."|";

        ?>
        <div class="imageEffectSampleImageHodlder" sEffect="<?php echo $name[0]; ?>"
             sEffectCategory="<?php echo $folderNames2; ?>"><img
                src="<?php echo $settingsValue['effectsFolder'] . '/' . $folderNames2 . '/' . $name[0] . '.png'; ?>"/>

            <p> <?php echo $name[0]; ?></p></div>
    <?php
    }/*for each image loop*/
    ?>

<?php
}/*if count $files is bigger then zero*/

?>
```

http://www.klick-bild.net/framegen/upload/images/Unbenannt.png

for example, the red box is how I imagine it (I added with paint)
whoever can kindly help me

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Generally with pagination you'll need to use $_GET to determine what to show on a certain page. It can be as simple or complex and you want to make it.

If you have everything in an array already, it can be done like this:

```
$i = 0; //current image
$start = $_GET['start']; //number to start on
$max = 5; //number per page

foreach ($images as $img) {
    if ($start > $i) continue;
    if ($i > ($start + $max)) break;

    echo "<img src='{$img}' />";
}
```

Then you need to draw the page number links

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= (len($array) / $max); $i++) {
    echo "<a href='./thispage.php?start=" . ($i * $max) . "'>{$i}</a>";
}
```

Comment: not working by me code foreach ($files as $name) {
        $path = explode('/', $name);
        $name = explode('.', $path[2]);
        //echo '<li id="'.$name[0].'" idf="'.$folderNames.'"><a href="#">'.$name[0].'</a></li>';
        //echo $name[0]."|";

        ?>
        <div class="imageEffectSampleImageHodlder" sEffect="<?php echo $name[0]; ?>"
             sEffectCategory="<?php echo $folderNames2; ?>"><img
                src="<?php echo $settingsValue['effectsFolder'] . '/' . $folderNames2 . '/' . $name[0] . '.png'; ?>"/>

            <p> <?php echo $name[0]; ?></p></div> the relevant

Comment: What exactly is 'not working'? Did you copy-paste my code straight into yours, or did you use the idea and edit it to work with your setup?

Comment: no copy to post i have what funktion code $i = 0;
foreach ($files as $name) {
if($i == 6) {break;}
$path=explode('/',$name);
    $name=explode('.',$path[2]);
         //echo '<li id="'.$name[0].'" idf="'.$folderNames.'"><a href="#">'.$name[0].'</a></li>';
         //echo $name[0]."|";
         $i++;      // Zähler um 1 erhöhen
   ?> <div class="imageEffectSampleImageHodlder" sEffect="<?php echo  $name[0]; ?>"  sEffectCategory="<?php echo $folderNames2; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $settingsValue['effectsFolder'].'/'.$folderNames2.'/'.$name[0] . '.png'; ?>"  /><p> <?php echo $name[0]; ?></p></div>

Comment: how can I generate a link which automatically adjusts Site: << | >>

Comment: Please post your code to the original post, so that it is legible! As far as << or >>, you need to determine what page you are on, and link to the next or previous page accordingly. `$page = ($start / $max);` For the next page `<a href="./thispage.php?start=<?php echo (($max & $page) + 1)">&gt;&gt;</a>` and previous page would be `<a href="./thispage.php?start=<?php echo (($max & ($page - 2)) + 1)">&lt;&lt;</a>`

Comment: I can not understand German I translate with google. because they can send me complete code? I do not know how I can format sorry